# Mime type for VCF file to open using google drive API

Tags: google-drive-android-api

What should be the MIME type for vcf files for google drive api.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics, here's a trick/hack I would use:

1. Go to [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com) and create / upload / ... one.
2. Use the [playground here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) (Try it! at the bottom) to find the file in question and look at the 'mimeType' field.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

try getting the mime type from file extension it worked for me.
here is the code:

```
 final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
 String tmptype = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("vcf");
```